# Provide custom rootpath to Nancy when using OWIN

Tags: nancy

I have a [sample application](https://github.com/bbaia/connect-owin-samples/) that shows how to host Nancy on node.js.

To do that I need to change the rootpath. I ended up with something like that:

```
public class Startup
{
    public static void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        string rootpath = app.Properties["node.rootpath"] as string;

        app.UseNancy(options => options.Bootstrapper = new NodeBootstrapper(rootpath));
    }
}

public class NodeRootPathProvider : IRootPathProvider
{
    private string rootpath;

    public NodeRootPathProvider(string rootpath)
    {
        this.rootpath = rootpath;
    }

    public string GetRootPath()
    {
        return this.rootpath;
    }
}

public class NodeBootstrapper : DefaultNancyBootstrapper
{
    private string rootpath;

    public NodeBootstrapper(string rootpath)
        : base()
    {
        this.rootpath = rootpath;
    }

    protected override IRootPathProvider RootPathProvider
    {
        get { return new NodeRootPathProvider(this.rootpath); }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to simplfy this?

Comment: I'd put NodeRootPathProvider as a nested private class within NoteBootstrapper. Otherwise, there's not much more to simplify here.